# Will multiple log properties run in Java Web App?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, logging, web-applications

I am working with Java Web App {Servlet + JSP + Tomcat} and having one log management for the **info** and **error** logs.

Now I want to add some actual data log functionality with different path name and property values. How can I achieve this in Java ?

**Existing Log Property**

```
<Configuration status="ALL" name="Logger" packages="">
    <Properties>
        <Property name="baseDir">D:\\Log\\</Property>
    </Properties>
    <Appenders>
        <RollingFile name="RollingFile" append="true" fileName="${baseDir}/Log.log" filePattern="${baseDir}/$${date:yyyy-MM}/app-%d{yyyy-MM-dd-HH}-%i.log.gz">
          <PatternLayout pattern="%d{dd/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} %msg %n"/>
            <Policies>
                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy />
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="30 MB" />         
            </Policies>
            <!-- Create 5 archives for the same date if the log file size exceeds 30MB -->
            <!-- Deletes the logs which are older than 60 days from the current date -->
            <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="5">
                <Delete basePath="${baseDir}" maxDepth="2">
                    <IfFileName glob="*/app-*.log.gz">
                        <IfLastModified age="60d" />
                    </IfFileName>
                </Delete>
            </DefaultRolloverStrategy>
        </RollingFile>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
      <Root level="ALL">
        <AppenderRef ref="RollingFile"/>
      </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

**Java**

```
public class Logj {

static Logger objLogger = LogManager.getLogger(Logj.class);

public static void doLog(Exception objException){
  objLogger.error("StackTrace - "+objException.fillInStackTrace());
}

public static void doActivityLog(String strActivityMessage){
  objLogger.info(" Activity - "+strActivityMessage);
}

}
```

I need same functionality to be execute for the new requirement

Will it support to add multiple Properties to add different directory path and adding multiple Appenders with different names ?

Thank in advance!!

Comment: Hey!! Any possibilities to achieve this ??

Answer (score 1):

You need to add one more property with different path in properties tag, 
along with add one more rolling file appender and refer that appender in the root level, that will create two logs.

Comment: Yeah!
It is creating the Log files, that is fine. But I am just confused to write the data to the newly created log file.

Present case
1. Writing the same logs in both the log files, I want to avoid this and It should write to specific file

Comment: for detailed info refer this - http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/customconfig.html and http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/customloglevels.html